# PHP str_replace Contents of HTML Element Based on Class

Tags: php, html, str-replace

I have a page that contains the following HTML element;

```
<p class="total"></p>
```

When the page loads I'd like to populate this with a line of text;

> 'Your total is:'

So, the html would look like;

```
<p class="total">Your total is:</p>
```

I've tried this but it's not working;

```
<?php
echo str_replace(".total", "Your total is:", "");
?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's multiple issues here. `str_replace()` just replaces a literal string with another in the string you pass (third argument). You're trying to find the string `.total` and replace it with `Your total is:` in an empty string `""`. PHP doesn't have a concept of html elements, css classes or html id's. It just sees strings so you can't search for `.total`. Just to add that text, you could probably do: `str_replace('<p class="total"></p>', '<p class="total">Your total is:</p>', $variableThatContainsAllTheHTML);`

Comment: @Syscall no it doesn't but the answer from @ Magnus Eriksson is perfect and does.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for this and the explanation! If you add an answer I'll accept :)

Comment: There is a DOM parser available for PHP which would potentially makes this easier / more robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `str_replace()` just replaces a literal string with another in the string you pass (third argument).

Example:

```
$foo = str_replace('lorem', 'foo', 'lorem bar');
// $foo now contains 'foo bar'
```

You're currently trying to find the string `.total` and replace it with `Your total is:` in an empty string `""`.

PHP doesn't have a concept of html elements, css classes or html id's. It just sees strings so you can't search for .total. Just to add that text, you could probably do:

```
str_replace('<p class="total"></p>', '<p class="total">Your total is:</p>', $theStringWithHtml);
```

---

If you rather search for the specific element, you can use PHP's [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).